# Reading a filestream into an XmlDocument skipping first line

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to read some XML files which sometimes have a non-xml descriptor line at the top. I'm reading them in as a FileStream and then trying to use:

```
var source = new FileStream(path);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(source);
```

Which of course fails with an error

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Is there a simple way to skip the first line and still use the filestream as the source for the `doc.Load()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StreamReader`, and just read the first line

```
using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\SomeXml.Xml", FileMode.Open);
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(line);

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(streamReader);
```